# How to get first X characters of string discarding the length of tags but keeping the tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, mootools, string-length

So, here I am wondering about the situation. Basically, I have a function which takes string as an input, cuts first 100 chars, makes "...More" link and the rest of the text is hidden. 
Now the thing is that the string can contain text formatting tags which are processed and affect the text (like bold, italic etc.), and the problem is I want, let's say, first 30 characters to be displayed like this:

```
    This is a text to be displayed...More
```

But what I get if there is, let's say, em tag:

```
    <em>This is</em> a text to be d...More
```

The tags themselves are not displayed, they add formatting (like it should be), but they still are counted when using .length. So what I get is

```
    *This is* a text to be d...More
```

My code now looks like this (with MooTools):

```
    p.each(function(mel){
        var t = mel.get('html');     //get all the content of p
        var str = t;                 //duplicate the string

        var div = new Element('div', {html:str});     //this function strips tags though don't know if it's useful here
        var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
        text;

        if (text.length<100) return;
        var tOne = t.substr(0,100);          //breaking text on visible and non-visible
        var tTwo = t.substr(101,t.length);     //all the further code works creating "More" after 100 characters
        var dots = new Element('span', {
            'class':'unedit',
            'text':'...'
        });
        var more = new Element('a', {
            href: '#',
            'class':'more unedit',
            'text':'More'
        });
        var unseen = new Element('span', {
            'class':'appended',
            'html':tTwo,
            styles: {
                'display':'none',
            }
        })
        var less = new Element('a', {
            href: '#',
            'class':'less unedit',
            'text':'Less'
        })
        unseen.grab(new Element('br'));
        unseen.grab(less);
        mel.set('html', tOne);
        mel.grab(dots);
        mel.grab(more);
        mel.grab(unseen);
    });
}
```

Not like it's a huge problem, just that visually all the paragraphs with formatting have different length of preview and it looks bad.

Comment: css instead? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pkt67khd/.  css text-overflow documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Using the idea @ant suggesting you could do like this: Make CSS hide content and use MooTools/JS to create the link and append something like `<a>...More</a>` in a new element/tag. This way CSS hides the original content and in a sibling element you get the link you want.

Comment: Thanks for ideas guys! I knew I was thinking in the wrong direction. Now works fine